# Nivoslider and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nivo-slider

Nivo slider and Twitter bootstrap do NOT like each other!

If you use thumbs you'll get all manners of madness being displayed.

I've found a css fix, I'll add below (to hopefully help others with this issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the css in nivo-slider.css from:

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

To

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    /* this is the fix */
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```